# Casting java primitives, does the JVM try to save memory?

Tags: java, primitive

```java
var foo = (short) 40 + (byte) 10
```

How many bytes does foo take up?
What is its type?

I would expect that the result is stored in a short, but to save memory does the JVM test to see if it will fit in a smaller primitive?

If it were `(short) 1 + (byte) 1` would it still be a short?

Comment: 4. The result of adding a short to a byte is an int, because the operands of + undergo binary numeric promotion.

Comment: It is actually likely to depend on where `foo` is defined: a class variable?  A local variable?  Either way, it's almost certainly an `int`.

Comment: It's an int. When you add smaller integral types, you get an int. So 4 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Rule of thumb*: integer arithmetic operations are *done as* `long` and result in `long` if either argument is `long`, `int` otherwise.

I also *suspect* that the JVM uses 4 bytes even to store `byte` and `short` (and `boolean`) variables - see [JVMS 2.6.1. Local Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1) and [Table 2.11.1-B](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1-320).

---

Even
`var test = (byte)1 + (byte)1`
will cause `test` to be an `int`.

Not the case for `var test = (byte)(1 + 1)`